# SQL: Help Doing Two Counts In One Query

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like so:

```
| user_id | client_application_id | invalidated_at
|       1 | 55555 | |
|       1 | 123   | |
```

I want to be able to do one thing:

1. Be able to count how many user_id's have more than 250 client_application_id's on their account and order it so that it starts at 250 and goes up.

My current (incorrect)query looks like so:

```
select  user_id, count(user_id) as cnt from tokens where invalidated_at is null group by user_id having count(user_id) > 250 order by cnt ;
```

The output looks like so:

```
  user_id   | cnt 
------------+-----
    1 | 251
    5 | 251
```

Using this example, I would like the query to count the two users that have 251, so it would look like so:

```
Count_Of_Users  | Application_Count
2 | 251
```

Comment: what's the problem ..  you have the user_id by the firts query  .. explain better your expected resul for the secondo query..

Comment: Edit your question and provide the desired output.

Comment: Updated it now, hopefully it's more clear

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to your query as a subquery and get the output you need:

```
    select count(user_id) as count_of_users, cnt as application_count from
    (
       select  user_id, count(client_application_id) as cnt 
       from tokens 
       where invalidated_at is null 
       group by user_id having count(client_application_id) > 250 
    ) t
    group by cnt
    order by cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear which is your expected result for the secondo query could be somthings like this

```
  select users.*, t.user_id, t.cnt 
  from users 
  inner join ( 

      select  user_id, count(user_id) as cnt 
      from tokens 
      where invalidated_at is null 
      group by user_id 
      having count(user_id) > 250 
  ) t on users.id = t.user_id 
  order by t.user_id
```